# How to persist an enum as string in Hibernate 6 Spring Boot 3 without using hibernate-types-62 in PostgreSQL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, enums

With the following postgresql database components and the removal of the @Type and @Typedef annotations in Spring Boot 3 (Hibernate 6), how do I persist an enum as a String in the database when the database also uses an Enum type for that column.

PG Database example:

```
CREATE TYPE TEST_TYPE AS ENUM ('TESTA','TESTB');

CREATE TABLE test_table (
    id     INT           NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    type   TEST_TYPE     NOT NULL
);
```

with the following Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_table")
public class TestTableEntity
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "type")
    private TestType tenantId;
}
```

This fails with an error because it attempts to persist it as a string instead of the enum type.

All other resources reference using the hypersistence-utils library, hibernate-types-62. However, I shouldn't need to be dependent on an external utils library.

The other solutions are clunky and require implementing a new hierarchy just for enums.

What is the simpler solution for PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use ColumnTransformers to alter the SQL generated by Hibernate.

This is a working example of the entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_table")
public class TestTableEntity
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "type")
    @ColumnTransformer(write = "?::TEST_TYPE")
    private TestType tenantId;
}
```

If it's part of a different schema, you may need to do

```
@ColumnTransformer(write = "?::other_table.TEST_TYPE")
```

If you inspect the SQL that is generated, this will use the @Enumerated annotation to pass the TestType as a string. The ColumnTransformer will then add the cast in for writing, allowing the DB's insert/update query to provide the correct parameter type for the intended column.

On the way back out, since we have @Enumerated configured to use String, Hibernate will figure out based on the stored String, which Enum to select and return.

This is a simple one-liner that doesn't require writing a custom UserType or pulling in a library just to support Enums.

Answer (score 2):

Since Hibernate 6.2, Hibernate uses `enum` types on MySQL by default.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/migration-guide/migration-guide.html#ddl-implicit-datatype-enum

For example, this code:

```java
    public enum TestType {
        TESTA, TESTB
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "test_table")
    public class TestTableEntity
    {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private int id;

        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        @Column(name = "type")
        private TestType tenantId;
    }
```

Produces the following DDL:

```sql
    create table test_table (
        id integer not null auto_increment,
        type enum ('TESTA','TESTB'),
        primary key (id)
    ) engine=InnoDB
```

So you don't have to do *anything* here, just upgrade to 6.2.

However, this is not yet implemented for PostgreSQL, which I guess is what you're using (you did not specify). The issue which proposes adding this is:

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16125

Comment: Yes! Thank you for calling this out, that'll be a good addition for future readers. I'll add a clarification for PostgreSQL specifically.