# Schema-Validation exception after migrating to Hibernate 6.2 with PostgreSQL custom ENUM datatypes

Tags: postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, orm

Exception ->

`org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [status] in table [user]; found ["status_enum" (Types#VARCHAR)], but expecting [status_enum (Types#OTHER)]`

### Old (working code)

`    import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.basic.PostgreSQLEnumType;
@TypeDef(name = "pgsql_enum", typeClass = PostgreSQLEnumType.class)
@Entity
(table info.....)

```
 (column info...)
 @Type(type = "pgsql_enum")
 @Column(name = "status", columnDefinition = "status_enum")
 private Status status;    `
```

Anyone here please help, who already working with postgresql custom ENUM datatypes.

[I found this but no luck.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76056263/how-to-persist-an-enum-as-string-in-hibernate-6-spring-boot-3-without-using-hibe)